# Is there any write-once USB stick/pendrive?

Tags: encryption, physical, usb-drive, physical-access

Is there any Write-once USB stick/Pendrive?

I need to submit some files to Authorities and I don't want them to modify on whatsoever.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you concerned about the integrity of the files when you get it back? Are you worried about them modifying it to create false evidence? Write-once flash drives aren't a solution to either of these.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Worried about them modifying it to create false evidence

Comment: If your law enforcement can fabricate evidence and use it against you then I'm afraid you're doomed. They won't even need to get a flash drive from you, they'll just "find" one in your possession that has the evidence they need to convict you.

Comment: Agree & good one !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a hash (with for example SHA256) or a [signature](https://jedisct1.github.io/minisign/) of the data you sumbit. This will be an electronic proof of (un)tampering. You can mandate a [notary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary) to keep a copy of the data and its hash or signature, to have a dated proof.

Even if you sumbit your data on a write-once medium, like a CD-R for example, nothing technically prevents the recipient to make a copy of the data then alter it. Its supporting medium can be copied too.